# begun vs. began vs. had become?

Tags: word-choice

1. As time went by, little by little, I **had begun** disappointed in something.
2. As time went by, little by little, I **began to be** disappointed in something.
3. As time went by, little by little, I **had become been** disappointed in something.

Which one is correct? And if everything is wrong could you tell me the most natural way of saying the sentence?

Answer (score 1):

Your second sentence is the only one that is correct at present.

There are a couple of things going on in your sentences:

**1) Be careful about whether you use gerunds (e.g., "being") or infinitives (e.g., "to be") after your main verbs.**

This is an extremely difficult part of English as there are not (as far as I know) any general rules to tell you what is appropriate after any given verb.  You just have to learn them one by one. But in this case...

"Begin" can be followed by a gerund or infinitive, so "began to be" (or "had begun to be") and "began being" (or "had begun being") would both be grammatically correct.

This is why your Sentence 1 is incorrect. You use a past tense form of a verb ("disappointed") when you need a gerund or infinitive.

**2) Not all verbs can be followed by gerunds and infinitives.**

There are many verbs after which we use neither gerunds nor infinitives!  "Become" is one example. Rather, we will use simple nouns or adjectives after "become", as in "He became a teacher" or "I became disappointed."

This is why your Sentence 3 is incorrect.

Comment: Oh, ok, I see. So if the first sentence was 'I had begun being (to be) disappointed', it would be also correct, right?

Comment: It would be **grammatically** correct.  But it does sound a bit unusual to me.  I would be more inclined to say "began **feeling** disappointed." I should note that my answer focused only on the grammar of your example sentences, but Mari-Lou A's answer gives some good advice about crafting a more natural-sounding sentence to get your point across.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest that the following sounds more natural.

> 1. As time went by, I *grew* **more and more disappointed** in [something]

The verb *grow* means something which increases in size  or volume over time.

The structure: **more + and + more + adjective** strongly hints at a continuous change

> To talk about how a person or thing is changing and gaining more of a particular quality, we can use two **-er** form adjectives connected by **and**, or we can use **more and more** before an adjective. We don’t follow such comparisons with than:
>
> 1. The weather is getting hotter and hotter.
> 2. I’m getting more and more interested in conservation these days.

[Cambridge, English Grammar Today](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/comparison-adjectives-bigger-biggest-more-interesting)

A simpler version of the OP's written examples would be

> 2. As time went by, little by little, I **began to feel** disappointed.